# How to load non timeseries data into simulink for use in a deep neural network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, structure, simulink

I trained a neural network in python and want to load the weights into simulink to pass into a function that will build the network. I thought I could use from workspace but it seems it does not handle non time series data for a structure. I get the error.

```
Invalid structure-format variable specified as workspace input in 'PMSM_FCS_MPC/From Workspace'. If
the input signal is a bus signal, the variable must be a structure of MATLAB timeseries objects.
Otherwise, the variable must include 'time' and 'signals' fields, and the 'signals' field must be a
structure with a 'values' field.
```

How can I pass a bunch of arrays into a simulink function?

Everything I have seen is about time series data. Nothing on a group of matrices such as would be used in a deep neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `From Workspace` block is designed to work with time-series data (as per the error message you show.)  There is no need to use it if you have constant data.

If you have non-time series data and you need it as a Simulink *signal* then use the name of the MATLAB variable as the parameter in a `Constant` block.  The signal coming out of the block will have the value of your data.

If you are using a `MATLAB Function` block then you can also input the data as a *parameter* argument to the function. See [Add Parameter Arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/parameter-arguments-in-matlab-function-block-functions.html) for the steps to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want to use the data. But if you have those weights as an array in the main workspace, you can simply reference to that variable in Simulink. For example if you have K = [1 2] in your workspace, you can use any block and type in K(1) or K(2). You can do also matrix operations and gather signals with Mux block.